# Finding the intersection of circles in Stewart's Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory, geometric-construction

On page 94 of Stewart's "Galois Theory", 4th edition, he leaves as an exercise the the case of the intersection of two circles.

He is proving that the pythagorean closure $\mathbb{Q}^{py}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains all constructible points. Taking $z$ in the intersection $C(z_1, \left|z_2 - z_3\right|) \cap C(z_4, \left|z_5 - z_6\right|)$ of two circles where $z_j \in \mathbb{Q}^{py}$ he arrives at

$(z - z_1) (\overline{z} - \overline{z_1}) = r^2$

$(z - z_4) (\overline{z} - \overline{z_4}) = s^2$

where $r = \left|z_2 - z_3\right|$ and $s = \left|z_5 - z_6\right|$. He says that one can solve in $z$ and $\overline{z}$ and get that $z$ satisfies a quadratic equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}^{py}$. I am having trouble proving that, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The main idea is: intersection two circles is the same than intersecting a circle and a line.

If you substract your two equations, you will get a linear equation in $z$ and $\bar{z}$, so you can write $\bar{z}$ under the form $az+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constructible (easy to see from the constructibility of the $z_j's$), then you can plug the expression of $\bar{z}$ into your first equation to get a quadratic equation satisfied by $z$, where the coefficients are also constructible.

Comment: Thank you very much!